# how to make a different list and chose a item from combobox VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have along list (about 500 items) separated into 4 list (each list has somethings in common)
but they will all appear in one combobox so the user will choose the item and the number of list should appear, if I want to use if statement like this:

If ComboBox3.SelectedItem = "Ferrous Gluconate" Or ComboBox3.SelectedItem = "Ferrous Sulfate" 
it would be a disaster

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  Are you wanting to prohibit the user from making the selection?  Do you want to allow the selection, but inform the user that it is invalid?

Comment: what is the question? Please give a sample input/output or write a bit more about your problem. Do you have some code? What have you tried? As it is this question will be closed quickly as there is no way to extract any meaning

Comment: What is the significance of the 4 lists?  A combo allows the user to select One item, those things are likely only a "disaster" when used in combination with somethign else - that whole comparison sounds like it is missing - at least from the question.

Comment: let me be more clear ....I have a list of drug names in combobox ...i want the a textbox show to which group does the drug (that was chosen by the user ) belong.....the items are 500 and they belong to 4 different groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the IndexOf function:

Define the lists:

```
Dim List1 As New List(Of String)
Dim List2 As New List(Of String)
Dim List3 As New List(Of String)
Dim List4 As New List(Of String)
```

Then simply do:

```
If Not List1.IndexOf(ComboBox3.SelectedItem) = -1 Then 'Item exists in list number 1
    Label1.Text = "<listnamehere>"
ElseIf Not List2.IndexOf(ComboBox3.SelectedItem) = -1 Then 'Item exists in list number 2
    Label1.Text = "<listnamehere>"
ElseIf Not List3.IndexOf(ComboBox3.SelectedItem) = -1 Then 'Item exists in list number 3
    Label1.Text = "<listnamehere>"
ElseIf Not List4.IndexOf(ComboBox3.SelectedItem) = -1 Then 'Item exists in list number 4
    Label1.Text = "<listnamehere>"
End If
```

Comment: one more thing, how to add the item into list1 for example

Comment: Can you explain your question a Little more? Do you want to add all items in the ComboBox? Or...?

Comment: how to make a list of 30 or 40 items ?i mean I want to add these 30 items under LIST 1 for example and another 30 Itesm under list 2 and so on

Comment: Dim List1 As New List(Of String) From {"I am", "a list", "of strings", ":D", "just keep", "doing like this and you'll be fine"}

Answer (score 0):

try adding custom attribute

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="No 1" Value="1" data-group="a"></asp:ListItem> 
    <asp:ListItem Text="No 2" Value="2" data-group="b"></asp:ListItem> 
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And from code behind, reference it like :

```
Dim Selected = DropDownList1.SelectedItem
If Selected IsNot Nothing Then
     'if Selected.Attributes("data-group") ="a" then
End If
```